# Adding parameters to an "Open With" application

Tags: filemanager

I can tell the file browser what application to open when I double-click a document, but can I also tell it what command line options to always use when opening that kind of document?

Comment: For example? What document, what application, what parameter?

Comment: I want Gvim to open a file (actually, any kind of file) with the --remote-tab-silent option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. By editing desktop application file (application/x-desktop) especially the `Exec` field.

You can start by choosing, for example, `nautilus.desktop` to be edited. Your desktop file usually located on `/usr/share/applications/`. Find the one you want to edit.

1. Open terminal and type up :

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Open the file with gedit through terminal :

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
   ```
3. Find `Exec` field and change the argument as you want. For example :

   ```
   ...
   Exec=nautilus --no-default-window --new-window %U
   ...
   ```
4. Save it. Done.